# Vuefire onAuthStateChanged returns user then null on refresh

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuefire

A while ago I built an application with firebase Vue & Vuefire. During development of this when I saved changes of this the application would stay signed in and would auto refresh my project. However I never realised until I picked it back up recently is that When you manually refresh the page this signs out the user. I am using signInWithEmailAndPassword as my only login option and whenever I sign in and refresh it on **onAuthStateChanged** observer I can see in my log's that a **user** is present and instantly after is the same log with the user being **null** and is never authenticated. I want it to re-authenticate and sign in which I thought it would do that automatically as the default authentication persistance **local** says

"Indicates that the state will be persisted even when the browser window is closed or the activity is destroyed in React Native. An explicit sign out is needed to clear that state. Note that Firebase Auth web sessions are single host origin and will be persisted for a single domain only."

My login code looks something like the below

```
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  }).then(function(){
    console.log('sign in');
```

Then the user is logged in and on refresh this code is called from Vuejs before created on the vue instance

```
  beforeCreate: function(){

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log("On Auth State Changed", user)
        if (!user) {
          console.log("User not logged in");
          // router.replace('/login'); 

        } else{

          // var credential;

          this.user = user;
          // https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/blob/master/src/vuefire.js#L169
          console.log('snapshot', user);

          user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
            console.log("Sign-in provider: " + profile.providerId);
            console.log("  Provider-specific UID: " + profile.uid);
            console.log("  Name: " + profile.displayName);
            console.log("  Email: " + profile.email);
            console.log("  Photo URL: " + profile.photoURL);
          });

          db.ref('posts/list').on('value', function(snapshot) {
                console.log(snapshot.val())
              }, function(error) {
                console.error(error);
              });
          // user.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken){
          //   console.log('NEW TOKEN: ', idToken);
          // });
          // router.replace('/');
        }
    }).bind(this);

  },
```

From this I see the console log's for the user but no database data. Directly after that I see **console.log("User not logged in");**

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Edited post with code snippets

Comment: It is normal that upon reloading the page, initially the `onAuthStateChanged` fires with `null`. But on most environments Firebase will then auto-restore the user authentication state, and (if that's successful) fire `onAuthStateChanged` again with the (now signed in) user. Is that not happening for you?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No that doesn't happen with me. It first returns a user then runs again and logs null. I understand that it should auto restore my authentication state but I literally can't get this to happen